# failed to fetch data from mongodb in dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

[image]I use mongoDB, after run server site 1st time all data load and display in UI. But whenever I try to show dynamic route using an event handler , and this give me those errors

**BSONTypeError:** Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
at new BSONType